# How to add new In-App Purchases after iPhone app is submitted

Tags: iphone, ios, dynamic, in-app-purchase

I am using [MK in-App Purchase](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-%E2%80%93-in-app-purchases/) and I want to make an application that have (let's say some books) and the books are getting added over time and each book the user have to buy it individually so how can I add with every book in-app purchase key for it without make an update for it.

I can't figure out a way so I need a step by step or a link for a tutorial for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would be the best way to set this up but if you are selling the books at certain price tiers (e.g. 1.99, 2.99, etc) I would set up a number of In App Purchases to reflect each price tier. Then when the user purchases a book match the appropriate tier to the book purchased.

You can set these up using the tutorial you already linked to in your question.

Comment: yeah this is good idea but i think when user buy another book with the same key it will give him message that this is already purchased and i'll not receive money :) .. any idea

Comment: Hey Mohamed, you could change the IAP type to be "consumable". This way the user will get charged each time they download a book. The only thing you will have to do is determine if the user is trying to download a book they have already bought so as to not charge them if he tries to download an already purchased book again.

Comment: yeah this is great idea.. i think i missed it cause of the hot weather of something.. thank u so much :) have a nice cold day

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update your current app to accept in-app purchases and process them accordingly. After adding support for in-app purchases, you will need to re-submit your updated app to Apple.

I have personally used [**`UrbanAirship`**](http://urbanairship.com/) in several of my projects. They offer tutorials on how to implement their in-app purchase solution into your app, which is quite easy.

Comment: Have you ever used Subscription using UrbanAirShip ? i